# Postgresql appending a prefix in a field if the prefix is not already there

Tags: postgresql

What I need to do is give the user a visual indication that a part is obsolete.  I can do this by appending "OBS-" to the front of the part description if the records obsolete flag is turned on.

My question is can someone think of a one line query that could be run that would update the description field in every record where the records obsolete flag is true, and the description does not already have "OBS-" at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE my_table
SET description = 'OBS-' || description 
WHERE obsolete AND left(description, 4) != 'OBS-';
```